# Вывод взаимоисключающих значений

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть 2 таблицы: House и Contract. Хочу сделать запрос: необходимо сравнить house_id в таблице Contract с id в таблице House. Мне нужно посмотреть квартиры, которых нет в таблице Contract. Мой вариант выводит совпадающие значения, если в Contract есть такой id, то он ищет такой же в house. А также вывести сопутствующую информацию помимо id. Как можно исправить этот момент?

Код:

```
select contract.house_id, house.id FROM Contract
INNER JOIN house ON contract.house_id = house.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT house.*, contract.house_id FROM house
LEFT JOIN contract on contract.house_id = house.id
WHERE contract.house_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Я немного ошибся, если можете подсказать, то скажите как помимо id в house ещё и всю информацию, которая есть в этой таблице вывести. Готов обновить топик.

Comment: @Blacit `house.*`

Comment: Спасибо, вижу. Обновляю топик.